# How to make series in HighCharts change Dynamically using Javascript and not Jquery

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have searched all over the Stack Overflow Website and can't find a Perfect Solution. So someone who is good at HighCharts can help me out.
Any answers will be Appreciated.....Please answer in Javascript and not Jquery....
    Generally I am creating empty variables in Series according to my usage.But I want them to be created dynamically when I add name and data in JSON file... I will attach my JSON File below...So please check it out...

```
var i = 1,
            chart;
        $(function () {
            chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: "This is a sample"
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Maths', 'Science', 'Telugu', 'English']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Marks'
                    }
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        name: "",
                        data: []
                    },
                    {
                        name: "",
                        data: []
                    },
                    {
                        name: "",
                        data: []
                    }
                ]
            });
        });

This is my json and when ever I add some name and data I want Series in Chart to add it....



        {
    "title":"My first chart",
    "dataa": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Unit Test 1",
            "data":[1,13,15,17,40,50,80]
        },
        {
            "name": "Unit Test 2",
            "data":[2,20,50,40,20,50,15]
        },
        {
            "name": "Unit Test 3",
            "data":[3,50,40,10,30,40,25]
        }
    ],

    "heading" :[  
    {
        "text":"S.No"
    },
    {
        "text":"Phy"
    },
    {
        "text":"Che"
    },
    {
        "text":"Mat"
    },
    {
        "text":"Sci"
    },
    {
        "text":"Tel"
    },
    {
        "text":"Eng"
    }
    ]  
}
```

Comment: your json  `dataa` is correct format as required by highcharts so directly pass `dataa` to series  as `series:dataa`

Comment: No my json has lot of data...Just I posted the data thats required for this post @Deep3015

Comment: I updated my code just check it @Deep3015

Comment: so add proper json sample

Comment: Ya edited bruh jst check it now @Deep3015

Comment: just refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/49870021/3898339 to see json. your json is incomplete

Comment: Ok I referred to the post...Ok lets assume I had the format u preferred and If data is present in same file, data:data works but now I have it in JSON File so How can I solve tat??? @Deep3015

Comment: check this tutorial https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript  then data is present in same file, and you can use data:data

Comment: No my data is not in the same file and its in JSON File...If data is in same file it works but I want it to work Dynamically...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169653/discussion-between-deep-3015-and-gvs-akhil).

Comment: So basically what you're trying to achieve is having a separate JSON file that can be updated. Whenever the update adds information about series' name and data some sort of listener mechanism should launch and apply it to Highcharts. Is that right?

Comment: Ya @KamilKulig tats my doubt exactly...

Comment: What exactly do you have problem with?

Comment: I just cant understand how to make series change dynamically when I update the data in JSON

Comment: You need some mechanism that'll be able to detect when the file changes (I'd recommend to find some library for this) and the update the series (`setData` is usually used for that kind of cases).

Comment: Can u write a small example for me pls.....@KamilKulig

Comment: I got the solution..But some prblem with it...can u solve @KamilKulig https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128746/highcharts-giving-an-extra-legend-when-i-get-data-dynamically-from-highcharts