# Highcharts giving an extra legend when I get data dynamically from Highcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I need to create highcharts series dynamically...So I used addSeries,But I am gettng an extra legend. If you have any other methods pls let me know...
I am not including my total chart code....I am jst placing my series in chart...

```
            $(function () {
                chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    series: [
                        {
                        }
                    ]

                });
            });


json:
    "dataa": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Unit Test 1",
            "data":[1,13,15,17,40,50,80]
        },
        {
            "name": "Unit Test 2",
            "data":[2,20,50,40,20,50,15]
        },
        {
            "name": "Unit Test 3",
            "data":[3,50,40,10,30,40,25]
        }
    ]

ajax:
 let dataeDatal=datae.dataa.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < dataeDatal; i++) {
                chart.addSeries({
                    data: datae.dataa[i].data,
                    name: datae.dataa[i].name
                });
            }
        }
```

[image: charts]

You can check in the image, I am getting an extra series1 legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should initialize your charts as

```
chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: []  //should be empty array
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2wgpv70/) demo